# UglifyJs break prod build...(react app...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build

How could my friend, pull ax49 (branch), use npm install (have uglify error)... and then use master (branch), and not be able to compile too with uglify error, that appears whereas it was OK just before compiling ax49 ? How npm, node module, or code could do that ?

---

I do not know what happened, I worked on my branch and get an error with the build-prod command I have :

> npm run build-prod --prefix .

This is the error (below). Then, I go to the master branch, to be sure it works at least as before, and I see that I have the same error.  I tried a new fresh install from master branch, and npm cache clear... and same error...

I really need a solution, feel desperate, 
- could you detect the error ?
- could I skip uglify task in react build prod process ?
- how to debug ?

TKS

```
> tgzapp@0.1.0 build-prod /Users/ax/0-ROOT/com/TGZ2/TogezerEngine/apolloClient
> better-npm-run build-prod

running better-npm-run in /Users/ax/0-ROOT/com/TGZ2/TogezerEngine/apolloClient
Executing script: build-prod

to be executed: npm-run-all -p build-css build-js

> tgzapp@0.1.0 build-css /Users/ax/0-ROOT/com/TGZ2/TogezerEngine/apolloClient
> lessc --clean-css="--compatibility=ie8 --advanced" src/index.less src/index.css


> tgzapp@0.1.0 build-js /Users/ax/0-ROOT/com/TGZ2/TogezerEngine/apolloClient
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

static/js/main.b7fb8e07.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (value) [./~/dotenv/lib/main.js:23,0]

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tgzapp@0.1.0 build-js: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tgzapp@0.1.0 build-js script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ax/.npm/_logs/2018-02-13T08_44_28_705Z-debug.log
ERROR: "build-js" exited with 1.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tgzapp@0.1.0 build-prod: `better-npm-run build-prod`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tgzapp@0.1.0 build-prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ax/.npm/_logs/2018-02-13T08_44_28_762Z-debug.log
```

Comment: are you using create-react-app?

Comment: I have also used create-react-app yes

Comment: I AM FURIOUS, AGAIN THE SAME ERROR. This create-react-app is a *****